# Issues that can arise when using UIViews instead of UIViewControllers?

Tags: objective-c, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I've been trying to figure out what can go wrong when using UIViews instead of UIViewControllers and haven't been able to find any therefore I've been just using custom UIViews when generally UIViewController is recommended for some reason.

I prefer UIViews mainly because when custom animating for transitions they're easier to manipulate as far as I know. Correct me if I'm wrong.
Also, I customize everything on my own programmatically such as tab bar, navigation bar etc hence to me, a custom UIView does everything a UIViewController does..

So, is using a separate custom UIView instead of a new UIViewController problematic? If so, please enlighten me..!

**Edit**

I am aware of MVC model and by *UIViews instead of UIViewControllers* I mean ignoring the whole one UIViewController per screen thing and use UIView as a container for all objects for certain screens.

For example, when showing menu screen, instead of pulling a UIViewController up for its own "section", I just don't do UIViewController at all and do it with a custom UIView which works as a container, draw/add everything in there. The same goes for the rest of "sections".(settings, option etc etc)

Is this problematic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I've been trying to figure out what can go wrong when using `UIView`s instead of `UIViewController`s

You cannot do it generally, because view objects and view controller objects occupy different places in the *Model-View-Controller* hierarchy. They are not even one-to-one with each other, because a single controller often manages multiple views.

> I prefer `UIView`s mainly because when custom animating for transitions they're easier to manipulate as far as I know.

In situations when a piece of functionality can reasonably go in either a view or in a view controller, it most likely belongs in the view, not in the view controller, so your observation is correct. Custom animation that can be encapsulated in a single `UIView` should be encapsulated in the `UIView`, even though the same code could go in a `UIViewController` as well.

Comment: @durazno To me, the edit does not change the question all that much: if you can do it in both places, you should probably do it in a view.

Comment: Really? I've read blogs and comments on here that strongly discourages the use of UIView when there's a section change in an app even though they don't give me anything convincing that it is actually problematic. Let's say, going from menu to game board. People seem to claim that going from MenuVC to GameVC is the only acceptable way and I don't see why I can't just use a custom view. So you say it's actually BETTER to use a custom view instead when possible?

Comment: @durazno If you can make a custom view for your menu, complete with a view delegate that encapsulates its interactions with the rest of the app, that's the way to go. Think of `UITableView`: iOS designers performed a nice separation of concerns here, letting `UITableView` worry about rendering and interacting with the user, while the app worries about feeding the table view its data - typically, through some code in the view controller. If you can do the same clean separation for your `MenuView`, that is how you should do it. If you do it well, you would be able to reuse a lot of code.

Comment: Awesome! Been very frustrated with this because I couldn't find out why I couldn't do what I was doing. Thanks!